# Почему при использовании dll в javaFX-проекте я получаю ошибку java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java, javafx, dll

В общем, проблема такая: необходимо использовать `.dll` в проекте на JavaFX. Файлы расположил в директории внутри проекта, в `application.properties` добавил `java.library.path` с путем до этой директории, в отдельном классе пытаюсь загрузить сам `.dll`:

```java
static {
    System.load("ps2000a.dll");
}
```

В этом же классе записал один из методов библиотеки:

```
public native Long ps2000aOpenUnit(Short handle, Byte serial);
```

При этом регулярно получаю ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: `ps2000a.dll`

Несмотря на то, что абсолютный путь и был задан. Также прописывал VM option с путем до директории с либами. Не очень понимаю, чего не хватает для запуска без ошибок.

Comment: ddl или dll или и то и другое?

Comment: по поводу абсолютного и относительного пути: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin только dll, ddl как то случайно написался...

Comment: `"ps2000a.dll"` это же не абсолютный путь. Чтобы загружать библиотеку по имени, без пути, можно использовать `System.loadLibrary("ps2000a")` -- туда передаётся только имя библиотеки, без расширения

Comment: @peterz я задавал путь через java.library.path и непосредственно в аргументе, ошибка при этом не меняется, к сожалению